# Golang TLS Accepted by browser but not by curl

Tags: ssl, curl, go

I'm creating a web app and normally I use nginx and lets encrypt for my SSL certificates, and that always works fine. I have nginx redirect the traffic to a different local server depending on the subdomain.

However, I decided that I wanted to try use golang's [ListenAndServeTLS](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS) function. So I set up my handles as normal and generated some signed certificates through lets encrypt and passed the file locations for the cert and the key to the ListenAndServeTLS function.

Now, for some reason, when accessing the site from a browser, I get no problems, it verifies the certificates and informs me that my connection is secure but using curl, I get the following response

```
$ curl https://...
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
HTTPS-proxy has similar options --proxy-cacert and --proxy-insecure.
```

I have never had this problem with nginx and I'm just wondering if anyone has any advice or has had this issue before and knows how to solve it.

Comment: Sounds like curl's CA bundle is out of date. The URL in the error message details how to fix this.

Comment: I have solved the issue. I checked my nginx config files and it turns out that it uses the fullchain.pem as the certificate rather than cert.pem. Easy assumption to make but solved now. Hope this helps any one else who has this problem.